# C# string concatenation - in-line vs. line-by-line

Tags: c#, string

C# code:

```
string first = "A"; 
first += "B"; 
first += "C";
string second = "D" + "E" + "F";
```

Generated IL code:

```
.locals init ([0] string first,
           [1] string second)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "A"
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldloc.0
  IL_0008:  ldstr      "B"
  IL_000d:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,
                                                              string)
  IL_0012:  stloc.0
  IL_0013:  ldloc.0
  IL_0014:  ldstr      "C"
  IL_0019:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,
                                                              string)
  IL_001e:  stloc.0
  IL_001f:  ldstr      "DEF"
  IL_0024:  stloc.1
  IL_0025:  ret
```

It is obvious that the in-line concatenation is a bit more efficient because it calls ldstr only once, but are there any other differences (for instance string objects created in memory?)

Thanks

Comment: It also *never calls `String.Concat()`*.

Comment: Useful read on the topic http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html

Comment: It's definitely due to the compiler realizing that "D", "E" and "F" are constants and can be rolled together at compile time, rather than at runtime.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Yes, putting `const` before `string` in each case and looking at the compiler errors shows this cquickly; "D" + "E" + "F" is a const expression. There's still more worth examining though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, precisely as you say - string objects created in memory.

Try turning the IL back into C# by hand. The code is pretty much equivalent to:

```
string first = "A";
string __temp = "B";
first = string.Concat(first, __temp);
__temp = "C";
first = string.Concat(first, __temp);

second = "DEF";
```

Further advantages can come down the line. As it is the following strings will be in the intern pool: "A", "B", "C", "DEF". Just what's more advantageous here depends on a few things, but it's likely that having the strings that are actually used in the pool is best, and "A", "B" & "C" aren't used except to create "ABC". In real code though, those substrings would likely be more signficant.

Most importantly though, note that this isn't a fair comparison between in-line vs. line by line. Try the following:

```
using(TextReader tr = new StreamReader(someFile))//no way for compiler to know what this will contain
{
  string a = tr.ReadLine();
  string b = tr.ReadLine();
  string c = tr.ReadLine();
  string d = tr.ReadLine();
  string e = tr.ReadLine();
  string f = tr.ReadLine();
  string first = a;
  first += b;
  first += c;
  string second = d + e + f;
}
```

Because the strings aren't hard-coded literals, the available optimisations are different, so the comparison between the two will differ. Yet more differences will be the case in other situations.

Comment: For those in suspense: the line-by-line calls will look pretty much the same (with a `String.Concat()` for each) whereas the in-line method will have *only a single `String.Concat()` call*. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wkb0y3w.aspx

Comment: Yep, which makes the second still beat the first, though not by as much.

Answer (score 3):

```
string second = "D" + "E" + "F";
```

got optimized to:

```
string second = "DEF";
```

Answer (score 2):

In the line-by-line case, the compiler does not have an optimization to notice that `line` has a value that can be known at compile time at every point.  In the single-line case, it does have that optimization.

I suspect only members of the C# compiler team can tell you with certainty why they did not optimize the first case, though I suspect it's due to the relative complexity of analyzing multiple lines of code compared to the relative benefit to C# programmers.

Comment: It's easy to see a reason why the former is less optimisable than the latter, by putting `const` before each string declaration. This is allowed on the second because it's a constant expression, not on the first. This isn't to say that a compiler couldn't also optimise the first, but we would be more surprised to find that the second wasn't, since constant expressions generally are.

Answer (score 0):

For constants it is dup of [C# Compile-Time Concatenation For String Constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764700/c-sharp-compile-time-concatenation-for-string-constants) (merges string constants).

Otherwise use StringBuilder and be happy.